# How to give a text a certain width in Python console?

Tags: python

I have Googled a lot, but couldn't find a proper solution for this. I have an output file that I get when I run my code. It works fine, but I want to `print` some stuff in a different way (*for example: in the middle, of slightly more to the right and so on)*, so I need to put some width on it.

I've noticed I can use `"\t"` this, but this is equal to 8 tabs and I can't seem to change it with `expandtabs()`. My question is: what is the simplest and best way to do this? I am used to CSS and HTML, so I am expecting some width function or something, but I can't find one.

I am just printing an ordinary string.

**What I have:**

```
"Blabla blabla" #string

"I don't want this text here" #string
```

**What I want:**

```
"Blabla blabla" #string

      "I want this text here for example" #string
```

Comment: Use `str.format` as per your use case. If you can provide some sample input and output, you might get a better response.

Comment: terminal/file output doesn't have a "width". If you want one, you have to enforce it by the way *you format* your output.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: I have added an example

Comment: What do you mean, to be precise @KarolyHorvath?